# get index value of an element from XML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

New to jQuery, I have a script that returns data from an XML file. What I need is the index number of the element returned. I know I can retreve a single element with this

```
name = $("sitelist:eq(1)",data).text();
```

but in my script I need to know each element position for the displayed data.
something like position = $(data,eq).value  .Can anyone help please .

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sites.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: displayXml
    });

    function displayXml(data) {
        $(data).find("course").each(function () {
            var name = $(this).find("sitelist").text();
            var line1 = $(this).find("address1").text();
        });
    }
}); // doc ready
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which node you need the index for, but if it is the `course` that you're iterating over with `.each()` you can get the index of each iteration from `.each()`

```
 $(data).find("course").each(function( idx ) {
      alert( idx ); // will alert the index of the current "course"

      var name = $(this).find("sitelist").text();
      var line1 = $(this).find("address1").text();
 });
```

If there's some other situation, you could try using the `.index()` method to get the index of the node from among its siblings. *It requires jQuery 1.4 or later.*

As in:

```
var $sitelist = $(this).find("sitelist");
var index = $sitelist.index();
var name = $sitelist.text();
```